# CSS: What is wrong with my responsive layout? Why does the text in responsive mode shrink so much?

Tags: css, responsive-design

What is wrong with my responsive layout? Why does the text in responsive mode shrink so much? How do I get the text to be a little larger in responsive mode?

Page is found here: http://spammysite.com/rtest.php

Here is screenshot of the text being too small, google chrome phone mode: https://snag.gy/agKCPp.jpg

Below is my code.

```
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}
p { 
    font-size: 12px;
}   

/* STRUCTURE */

#pagewrap {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
header {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
#middle {
    width: 616px; /* Account for margins + border values */
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 270px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    float: left;
}
footer {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

/************************************************************************************
MEDIA QUERIES
*************************************************************************************/
/* for 980px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    p { 
        font-size: 12px;
    }   
    #pagewrap {
        width: 94%;
    }
    #middle {
        width: 92%;
        padding: 1% 4%;
        margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        float: right;
    }

    #sidebar {
        clear: both;
        padding: 1% 4%;
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

    header, footer {
        padding: 1% 4%;
    }
}

/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    p { 
        font-size: 20px;
    }   
    #middle {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    #sidebar {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

}

/* for 480px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    p { 
        font-size: 20px;
    }   
    header {
        height: auto;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    #sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
#sidebar {
    background: #f0efef;
}
header, #content, #middle, #sidebar {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#pagewrap, header, #content, #middle, #sidebar, footer {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
</style>

<div id="pagewrap">

    <header>
        Layout
    </header>

    <section id="middle">
        Middle Section
    </section>

    <aside id="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </aside>

    <footer>
        Footer text
    </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "responsive mode" and with "shrink"?

Comment: I see it normal sized at all resolutions

Comment: Lorenzo Marcon, is correct. I do not see the issue that you are describing.

Comment: I see it like this: http://imgur.com/a/5wfR2 which is the expected behaviour

Comment: Is it an issue with Google Chrome?  Here is screenshot of the text being too small, google chrome phone mode: https://snag.gy/agKCPp.jpg

Comment: You probably want to start by specifying how your page should be displayed with a `viewport` meta tag. Right now it might be that automatic zooming plays tricks on you.

Comment: using `vw` or `vh` instead of `%`

Comment: Maybe you want your text in a <p> tag?

Comment: The monitor you are using, if it has a high pixel density ratio could make it appear that the screen is shrinking when using chrome screen simulation, make a media query to increase the font size on smaller high pixed density devices.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

The below tag fixed the issue

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```